# How can I get wonder animations in multiplayer?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

In singleplayer, there's an animation that plays for wonders. Is there a way I can get this in multiplayer?

When I try commenting out the check if the game is multiplayer in WonderBuiltPopUp.lua and NaturalWonderPopup.lua example it focuses the camera on it but doesn't show the animation. We need a mod or a way to get these animations in multiplayer!!!

Answer (score 2):

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/av3oe1/multiplayer_need_help_to_get_features_popups/) says that if you comment out lines 243 to 245 of `steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization VI\Base\Assets\UI\Popups\NaturalWonderPopup.lua` it will restore the Natural Wonder cinematic (not the Wonder built however):

```
-- Because these popup movies lock the engine until complete; disable 
-- them if playing in any type of multiplayer game.
-- if GameConfiguration.IsAnyMultiplayer() or GameConfiguration.IsHotseat() then
--  return;
-- end
```

Although it's listed as untested, there's a comment stating it does work, but can cause an issue in certain circumstances:

> There is a problem where if the natural wonder is discovered during the Please Wait phase(like if your scout is following a long distance move order over many turns and encounters the natural wonder after you hit End Turn), it plays the movie but gets stuck because the X button to dismiss the movie is lost behind the Please Wait overlay. This causes the game to soft hang.

Hitting escape usually dismisses pop ups in civ 6, so that might be a workaround.